# Executing shellcode in shared memory with mmap

Tags: c, shared-memory, mmap, shellcode

I'm trying to place and execute program-code into a shared-memory region. Initializing and allocating the shared memory as well as copying the shellcode into the "new" memory works as intended, but as soon as I try to execute it, it doesn't work. Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

I think that `write(1, 0x6000d8, 13) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)`might be the error? What might be causing this?

I included the code and the stract error output. The C-code is based on an answer from [Adam Rosenfield](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9530/adam-rosenfield) in [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19749664/7981046).

**The C-Code**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

// My own shellcode, obtained through objdump
// works on its own (a hello world-program)
const char shellcode[] = "\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00\xbf\x01\x00\x00\x00\x48\xbe\xd8\x00\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xba\x0d\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x05\xb8\x3c\x00\x00\x00\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x05";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void *mem = mmap(0, sizeof(shellcode), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

    memcpy(mem, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode));

    mprotect(mem, sizeof(shellcode), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC);

    int (*func)();
    func = (int (*)())mem;
    (int)(*func)();

    munmap(mem, sizeof(shellcode));

    return 0;
}
```

***Strace Log***

```
execve("./memory", ["./memory"], [/* 17 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL) = 0x557b5e17e000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb8ba434000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=92611, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 92611, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb8ba41d000
close(3) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20\5\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1856752, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3959200, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fb8b9e4c000
mprotect(0x7fb8ba009000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fb8ba209000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1bd000) = 0x7fb8ba209000
mmap(0x7fb8ba20f000, 14752, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb8ba20f000
close(3) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb8ba41b000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fb8ba41b700) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb8ba209000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x557b5dd04000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fb8ba437000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fb8ba41d000, 92611)           = 0
mmap(NULL, 40, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fb8ba433000
mprotect(0x7fb8ba433000, 40, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC) = 0
write(1, 0x6000d8, 13) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
exit(0) = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

***The source of the shellcode***

```
section .data
    msg db      "hello, world!"

section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov     rax, 1
    mov     rdi, 1
    mov     rsi, msg
    mov     rdx, 13
    syscall
    mov    rax, 60
    mov    rdi, 0
    syscall
```

Comment: It looks like your shellcode somewhat worked.  The value `\xd8\x00\x60\x00` looks like the invalid address `0x6000d8` that was passed to `write()`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle So the problem might be the shell code, right? The address that the shellcode "uses" is wrong?

Comment: Have you got the source code of the shell code? If yes post it.

Comment: Sure @LPs, I just added it to my original post!

Comment: It smells that `"hello, world!"` string, stored in `.data segment`, is not reachable when shell code was copied. Moreover your shell code array should have the `"hello, world!"` string somewhere. Something like `\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply the proposed duplicate to your code

When you inject this shell code, you don't know what is at message:

```
mov     rsi, msg
```

in the injected process, it can be anything but it will not be `"Hello world!\r\n"` since it is in the `.data section`

```
section .data
    msg db      "hello, world!"
```

while you dumped only the .text section.

You can see that your shell code doesn't have  `"Hello world!\r\n"` (`\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f....`)

Comment: Thanks @LPs, this was indeed the case. I changed `mov rsi, msg` to `pop rsi` and it worked like a charm.